# Center text in button Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So the XMAL I have is this:

```
<Button x:Name="button_equal" Content="=" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="253,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="73" Click="button_equal_Click" FontSize="45" RenderTransformOrigin="0.507,0.499" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

and the result in this:

[image]

As you can see it is not really centered although I am using

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
```

Is there any way i can use something more specific instead of "center" "right" "left" etc. ?

Comment: I would say the problem regarding the centring might be due to the RenderTranformOrigin. Because besides that all seem pretty correct to me. So if you remove it, the = should be displayed centered

Comment: just removed it still the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer you can use

```
<Button x:Name="button_equal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="253,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="73" Click="button_equal_Click" FontSize="45" RenderTransformOrigin="0.507,0.499" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="="/>
</Button>
```

Then it will definately be central rather than using padding.

EDIT:
It's the font. Segoe UI doesn't centre the "=" character. Change the font to "Global User Interface" and it will be centered:

[image]

Comment: well its still not centered :P

Comment: In which case padding's your best option if you're going to use text.

Comment: yep you are right about the font thank you!But shouldnt the HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" center it ?

Comment: It centers the actual text block element, but that draws the character more than halfway down the available space

Comment: Its very bad xaml design to put margins like 200 and all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use padding property, example:

```
Padding="0,0,0,2"
```

Comment: Yep that did it,but it gets glitchy for some reason in bigger fonts.

Comment: @harambe note that this depends on a text you use. If you will do `Content="_"` - it will not be centered again, even with given padding.